# How can I do a variable number of POST requests synchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an array of `items` that needs to be `POST`ed in order.

```
var items = ["data 1", "data 2", etc];
while (i < numOfItems) {    
    var formData = {
        ID : ID,
        UID : UID,
        item : items[i];
    }
    request.post({url:'http://example.com/a', formData: formData}, function(err, httpResponse, body){ 
        if (err) {
            return console.error('Post failed:', err);
        }
        console.log('Post successful!  Server responded with:', body);
        i++;
    });
}
```

This creates an infinite loop. How can I synchronize a variable number of requests?

Thanks!

Comment: do you want each request to wait for the previous to finish before commencing?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution with the code you posted is recursion

```
var items = ["data 1", "data 2", etc];
function doRequest(i) {
    if (i< numOfItems) {
        var formData = {
            ID : ID,
            UID : UID,
            item : items[i];
        }
        request.post({url:'http://example.com/a', formData: formData}, function(err, httpResponse, body){ 
            if (err) {
                // this will stop the "loop" altogether
                return console.error('Post failed:', err);
            }
            console.log('Post successful!  Server responded with:', body);
            doRequest(++i);
        });
    }
}
```